# Save HTML page as pdf

Tags: angularjs, sails.js

How can I save HTML as PDF using angular and sailsjs?

I have view made by angularjs and i need to download it or view it with pdf reader.

Answer (score 0):

I've had better luck with wkhtmltopdf (https://www.npmjs.com/package/wkhtmltopdf) although it requires installing separately before you can use the npm package.

You can pass your rendered HTML as a string parameter.

Answer (score -1):

I would highly suggest using a node implementation of [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html). It will allow you to render a page and save it as PDF .
You may use this [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantom) in order to allow node to control Phantom.